# Join queries from sp_MSForEachTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-msforeachtable

I'm using the following query to get the times when a table was last updadted by users:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName, 
                                  last_user_update,
                                  user_updates,
                                  index_id
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID(''SP3D_DB_RESEARCH_MDB'') AND 
                    OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(''?'')'
```

But in the results window I get like a table with one row for each result. Is there any way to join them as an unique query so I can sort the results?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not `JOIN` with the procedure but you will be able to get the result into one (temp)Table(variable), which you might use for joins in a second step using `INSERT INTO` with the `EXEC`. e.g.

```
Declare @Collect Table (Name Varchar(100),cnt integer)
Insert into @Collect
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'' as TableName,Count(*) from ?' 
Select * from @Collect
```

Comment: @RBasniak testet on SQLServer 2005 and  SQLServer 2008 even fiddle is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5e25/1

Comment: Worked now, I changed the SELECT to a specific database and it worked. Thanks